Loop over multiple values of different type and call a generic function each time
There's a function I want to call multiple times, that includes the generic import parameter type any:
CLASS-METHODS generic_method
  IMPORTING
    param_value TYPE any
    param_name  TYPE char30
  CHANGING
    parameters  TYPE some_table_type.

Instead of using it like this as I did before:
DATA(parameters) = VALUE some_table_type( ).

z_my_class=>generic_method(
  EXPORTING
    param_value = p_id
    param_name  = z_if_constants=>parameters-p_id
  CHANGING
    parameters  = parameters ).

z_my_class=>generic_method(
  EXPORTING
    param_value = p_name
    param_name  = z_if_constants=>parameters-p_name
  CHANGING
    parameters  = parameters ).

"...and so on

I want to create a loop but it won't let me as it is not possible to define a structure with a field of type any:
"Defining the table structure + type
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF param_name_value_pair,
    name  TYPE string,
    value TYPE any, ""ANY" is a generic type. Use this type only for typing field symbols and formal parameters.
  END OF param_name_value_pair.
TYPES: 
  param_key_value_pairs TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF param_name_value_pair WITH DEFAULT KEY.

" Create internal table and loop over it
LOOP AT VALUE param_key_value_pairs( 
    ( name = z_if_constants=>parameters-p_id   value = p_id ) 
    ( name = z_if_constants=>parameters-p_name value = p_name ) 
  ) 
  REFERENCE INTO DATA(param_key_value).

  z_my_class=>generic_method(
    EXPORTING
      param_value = param_key_value-value
      param_name  = param_key_value-name
    CHANGING
      parameters  = parameters ).
ENDLOOP.

Is there an easy way to solve this with such a loop without getting an error?

Use data reference types (type ref to data) and adjust the rest of the program (value = REF #( p_id ), ASSIGN param_key_value-value->* TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<any>), EXPORTING param_value = <any>, etc.)

Is it necessary to have the type inside the generic method? An option would be to always send as a string
